# How to resize a global std::vector of std::mutex once it's been defined?

Tags: c++, vector, global-variables, mutex

I am trying to use a vector of mutexes, but want to resize them after they are defined.
However, I am getting a compilation error

***error: static_assert failed due to requirement 'is_constructible<std::mutex, std::mutex &&>::value' "result type must be constructible from value type of input range"
static_assert(is_constructible<_ValueType2, decltype(*__first)>::value,***

Here is the code in godbolt

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <mutex>

std::vector<std::mutex> g_v(4);

int main() { 
    g_v.resize(2);
    std::cout<<"v.size() =  " << g_v.size()<<'\n';
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/K85MEPM8E

Could someone explain the meaning of such an error message and how to solve the issue?

Comment: `std::mutex` can't be copied or moved.

Comment: I guess the real question is why you want to resize a vector of mutexes.

Comment: resize might require to reallocate and that wont work with `std::mutex`, wether it actually has to reallocate is only known at runtime, thats why it fails even if you do not reallocate

Comment: fwiw you can `pop_back`. https://godbolt.org/z/4dKhenMqr.

Comment: Thank you all, @463035818_is_not_a_number pop_back is a good option, tested your change in godbolt. The reason is to keep size limited to the actual need and do that once.